# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XX

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple JPA/Hibernate Project in Eclipse (Helios) IDE.
I have placed the persistence.xml in Project>resources dir.
And in Eclipse i have added this directory(Project\resources) to the classpath.

Yet when i run my appln frm within Eclipse IDE, i see this error:
**javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XX**

In Eclipse, i've following Libraries:
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar
and rest are supporting jars...

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="XX" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-- the JNDI data source -->
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/tutorialDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What is causing this error in Eclipse IDE?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**So the solution**:

In Eclipse > Properties > Java Build Path
Source Tab - there was: Excluded: META-INF/
This was causing the META-INF dir to be completely ignored, and persistence.xml was not found.
On deleting that Excluded:META-INF/ line, persistence.xml is now found successfully.

**How did- Excluded: META-INF/ end up in Java Build Path > 'Source' tab?**
Earlier under the 'Libraries' Tab, i had done: 'Add Class Folder' : src/META-INF
This automatically resulted in Excluded: META-INF/ under 'Source' tab.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The persistence.xml must be placed inside META-INF directory.

Edit: don't forget include the library of the driver for your database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to keep this persistence.xml file into class path `META-INF` folder.

```
{CLASS_PATH}/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Comment: Yes... i hv tried that, thats where its original location was - it does not help.

Comment: @Jasper, where you have defined your , java:comp/env/jdbc/tutorialDS? Could you please make sure your data source is accessible

Comment: I have deleted that line, and it makes no diff. Its as if persistence.xml is just not found.

Comment: Shammim> i just figured out the problem, pls see my answer. It was a mistake on my part. Thanks for your insights though.